# API request is not returning the value properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I need to validate a CSV file on the site [CSVLint](https://csvlint.io)
Guide on using the API can be found [here](https://csvlint.io/documentation).

The problem is that when I request a JSON file from the site, I don't get a proper response, I get an empty list. When I access the site from the browser using the authentication link, I get the full authentication results.
What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
import requests


data = {
  'urls[]': 'https://www.wien.gv.at/statistik/ogd/vie_104.csv'
}
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'
header={'User-Agent' : user_agent }

response = requests.post('http://csvlint.io/package.json', data=data,headers=header)
first=response.json()
csvid=first['package']['url']+'.json'
#link='https'+csvid[5:]

request=requests.get(csvid).text
print(request)
```

The aim is to get the content of `csvid` JSON link.
In Python, in `print(request)` I get:

```
{"version":"0.1","licence":"http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/","package":{"validations":[]}}
```

In browser I get:

```
{"version":"0.1","licence":"http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/","package":{"validations":[{"url":"https://csvlint.io/validation/5c937a85b1b6fc0004000047","source":"https://www.wien.gv.at/statistik/ogd/vie_104.csv","state":"warnings"}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to simply delay your request like so:

```
import time
import requests


data = {
  'urls[]': 'https://www.wien.gv.at/statistik/ogd/vie_104.csv'
}
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'
header={'User-Agent' : user_agent }

response = requests.post('http://csvlint.io/package.json', data=data,headers=header)
first=response.json()
csvid=first['package']['url']+'.json'

time.sleep(5)

request=requests.get(csvid).text
print(request)
```

I get the correct output with this modification:

> {"version":"0.1","licence":"http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/","package":{"validations":[{"url":"https://csvlint.io/validation/5c937a85b1b6fc0004000047","source":"https://www.wien.gv.at/statistik/ogd/vie_104.csv","state":"warnings"}]}}

This is due to the way the package is handled with their API, as pointed out in another answer:

> Note Currently the package is created in the background, so may not be
>   available immediately. This will change in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification, I did not understand what was meant by saying that the package is not immediately available.

Answer (score 0):

There is a line in the API guidance that says:

> Note Currently the package is created in the background, so may not be
>   available immediately. This will change in the future.

This is right at the stage where you are getting the empty return. Indeed, even with selenium a refresh is needed for info to appear.

It may be that you currently need a method like selenium for this step and possibly the final one. At the very least a delay for package to become ready.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import json 

d = webdriver.Chrome()

data = {
  'urls[]': 'https://www.wien.gv.at/statistik/ogd/vie_104.csv'
}
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'
header={'User-Agent' : user_agent }

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.post('http://csvlint.io/package.json', data=data,headers=header)
    first = response.json()
    csvid = first['package']['url'] + '.json'
    d.get(csvid)
    d.refresh()
    data = WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "pre"))).text    
    validationUrl = json.loads(data)['package']['validations'][0]['url']   
    final  = s.get(validationUrl + '.json').json()
    print(final)
    d.quit()
```